# Given a unitary matrix, output the gate name using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, pauli-gates

Given a unitary matrix of a unknown gate, can we write a program in Qiskit to output the name of the corresponding gate if that is a standard gate?
So suppose I have $U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, I want Qiskit to output the Pauli $X$ gate name.

Comment: Using Simone's methodology, you could also search for specific multiples, fractions, or powers of gates, including the square roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Qiskit itself has some functionality to directly get what you want but you could implement it by yourself using something like the following:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isclass
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit.library import standard_gates


def get_qiskit_gate(u):
    for name, gate in getmembers(standard_gates, isclass):
        try:
            unitary = gate().__array__()
        except:
            continue
        if unitary.shape == u.shape and np.allclose(unitary, u):
            return name
```

However, this will work only for standard gates (defined in the [`qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/tree/main/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates) module) that implement the `__array__` attribute. If the given unitary `u` does not correspond to any of these gates, the function will simply returns `None`.

Here is an example for the Pauli $X$ gate:

```
unitary = np.array([[0, 1],
                    [1, 0]])

print(get_qiskit_gate(u=unitary))
```

`XGate`

Comment: Also can you please tell me if I have a standard gate, how can I get its unitary matrix from qiskit

Comment: Please open a new question and add some more details about what you need to do

Comment: unitary = np.array([[0.707, 0.707],
                    [0.707,- 0.707]]). 
Why isn't the code outputting hadamard for the above unitary matrix

Comment: That happens simply because of the [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) finite precision when comparing the array `unitary` with the array `u`. If you put 0.7071, it works fine; `unitary = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]]) / np.sqrt(2)` would be even better